# how to make captcha case sensitive in phpfox

Tags: captcha, phpfox

My Dear Buddies,

I need your help to make captcha case sensitive phpfox,

i want to make captcha not case sensitive in my phpfox site. please help me.
i can not find code for change case sensitivity in phpfox captcha module, and there is no any settings in phpfox backend for that so ple help me.
here is code of

**captcha.class.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * [PHPFOX_HEADER]
 */

defined('PHPFOX') or exit('NO DICE!');

/**
 * 
 * 
 * @copyright       [PHPFOX_COPYRIGHT]
 * @author          Raymond Benc
 * @package         Module_Captcha
 * @version         $Id: captcha.class.php 6005 2013-06-06 14:12:12Z Raymond_Benc $
 */
class Captcha_Service_Captcha extends Phpfox_Service 
{
    private $_oSession;

    /**
     * Class constructor
     */ 
    public function __construct()
    {       
        $this->_oSession = Phpfox::getService('log.session');
    }

    public function checkHash($sCode = null)
    {

        if (Phpfox::getParam('captcha.recaptcha'))
        {

            require_once(PHPFOX_DIR_LIB . 'recaptcha' . PHPFOX_DS . 'recaptchalib.php');        
            if (isset($_POST["recaptcha_response_field"])) 
            {           
                $oResp = recaptcha_check_answer(Phpfox::getParam('captcha.recaptcha_private_key'), $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"], $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"], $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

                if ($oResp->is_valid){          
                    return true;
                }else{               
                    return false;
                }           
            }   

            return false;
        }       

        if (Phpfox::getParam('core.store_only_users_in_session'))
        {

            $oSession = Phpfox::getLib('session');

            $sSessionHash = $oSession->get('sessionhash');

            $aRow = $this->database()->select('*')
                ->from(Phpfox::getT('log_session'))
                ->where('session_hash = \'' . $this->database()->escape($sSessionHash) . '\'')
                ->execute('getSlaveRow');

            if (isset($aRow['session_hash']) && $this->_getHash(strtolower($sCode), $aRow['session_hash']) == $aRow['captcha_hash'])
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        else
        {

            if ($this->_getHash(strtolower($sCode), $this->_oSession->getSessionId()) == $this->_oSession->get('captcha_hash'))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function setHash($sCode)
    {
        if (Phpfox::getParam('core.store_only_users_in_session'))
        {
            $oRequest = Phpfox_Request::instance();
            $oSession = Phpfox::getLib('session');

            $sSessionHash = $oSession->get('sessionhash');
            $bCreate = true;

            if (!empty($sSessionHash))
            {
                $bCreate = false;
                $aRow = $this->database()->select('*')
                    ->from(Phpfox::getT('log_session'))
                    ->where('session_hash = \'' . $this->database()->escape($sSessionHash) . '\'')
                    ->execute('getSlaveRow');

                if (isset($aRow['session_hash']))
                {
                    $this->database()->update(Phpfox::getT('log_session'), array('captcha_hash' => $this->_getHash($sCode, $sSessionHash)), "session_hash = '" . $sSessionHash . "'");
                }
                else
                {
                    $bCreate = true;
                }
            }

            if ($bCreate)
            {
                $sSessionHash = $oRequest->getSessionHash();
                $this->database()->insert(Phpfox::getT('log_session'), array(
                        'session_hash' => $sSessionHash,
                        'id_hash' => $oRequest->getIdHash(),
                        'captcha_hash' => $this->_getHash($sCode, $sSessionHash),
                        'user_id' => Phpfox::getUserId(),
                        'last_activity' => PHPFOX_TIME,
                        'location' => '',
                        'is_forum' => '0',
                        'forum_id' => 0,
                        'im_hide' => 0,
                        'ip_address' => '',
                        'user_agent' => ''
                    )
                );
                $oSession->set('sessionhash', $sSessionHash);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $iId = $this->_oSession->getSessionId();

            $this->database()->update(Phpfox::getT('log_session'), array('captcha_hash' => $this->_getHash($sCode, $iId)), "session_hash = '" . $iId . "'");
        }
    }

    public function displayCaptcha($sText)
    {
        ((Phpfox::getParam('captcha.captcha_use_font') && function_exists('imagettftext')) ? $this->_writeFromFont($sText) : $this->_writeFromString($sText));

        ob_clean();

        header("X-Content-Encoded-By: phpFox " . PhpFox::getVersion());
        header("Pragma: no-cache");
        header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate'); 
        header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

        imagejpeg($this->_hImg);    
        imagedestroy($this->_hImg);     
    }   

    public function generateCode($sCharacters) 
    {   
        $sPossible = Phpfox::getParam('captcha.captcha_code');
        $sCode = '';
        $i = 0;
        while ($i < $sCharacters) 
        { 
            $sCode .= substr($sPossible, mt_rand(0, strlen($sPossible)-1), 1);
            $i++;
        }      
        return strtolower($sCode);
    }       

    /**
     * If a call is made to an unknown method attempt to connect
     * it to a specific plug-in with the same name thus allowing 
     * plug-in developers the ability to extend classes.
     *
     * @param string $sMethod is the name of the method
     * @param array $aArguments is the array of arguments of being passed
     */
    public function __call($sMethod, $aArguments)
    {
        /**
         * Check if such a plug-in exists and if it does call it.
         */
        if ($sPlugin = Phpfox_Plugin::get('captcha.service_captcha__call'))
        {
            return eval($sPlugin);
        }

        /**
         * No method or plug-in found we must throw a error.
         */
        Phpfox_Error::trigger('Call to undefined method ' . __CLASS__ . '::' . $sMethod . '()', E_USER_ERROR);
    }       

    private function _getHash($sCode, $sSalt)
    {
        return md5(md5($sCode) . $sSalt);
    }

    private function _writeFromFont($sText)
    {
        $iString = strlen($sText);
        $iWidth = (($iString + 5) * 10 * 2);
        $iHeight = 45;
        $iTextSize = 20;
        $sFont = Phpfox::getParam('core.dir_static') . 'image/font/' . Phpfox::getParam('captcha.captcha_font');

        if (!file_exists($sFont))
        {
            return $this->_writeFromString($sText);
        }

        $this->_imageCreate($iWidth, $iHeight);

        $nBgColor  = imageColorAllocate($this->_hImg, 255, 255, 255);
        $nTxtColor = imageColorAllocate($this->_hImg, 0, 0, 0);     

        if (!($aBox = @imagettfbbox($iTextSize, 0, $sFont, $sText)))
        {
            return $this->_writeFromString($sText);
        }

        //Find out the width and height of the text box
        $iTextW = $aBox[2] - $aBox[0];
        $iTextH = $aBox[5] - $aBox[3];        

        if (function_exists('imagefilledellipse'))
        {
            $nNoiseColor = imagecolorallocate($this->_hImg, 207, 181, 181);
            for ($i = 0; $i < ($iWidth*$iHeight) / 3; $i++)
            {
                imagefilledellipse($this->_hImg, mt_rand(0, $iWidth), mt_rand(0, $iHeight), 1, 1, $nNoiseColor);
            }
        }

        $iImageLineColor = imagecolorallocate($this->_hImg, 207, 181, 181);
        for ($i = 0; $i < ($iWidth*$iHeight) / 150; $i++)
        {
            imageline($this->_hImg, mt_rand(0, $iWidth), mt_rand(0, $iHeight), mt_rand(0, $iWidth), mt_rand(0, $iHeight), $iImageLineColor);
        }       

        // Calculate the positions
        $positionLeft = (($iWidth - $iTextW) / 2) - (20 + $iString);
        $positionTop = (($iHeight - $iTextH) / 2);

        for ($i = 0; $i < $iString; $i++) 
        { 
            if (!@imagettftext($this->_hImg, $iTextSize, 0, $positionLeft, 30, $nTxtColor, $sFont, $sText[$i]))
            {
                return $this->_writeFromString($sText);
            }

            $positionLeft += 20;
        }
    }

    private function _writeFromString($sText)
    {
        $iString = strlen($sText);
        $iWidth = (($iString + 5) * 6.4 * 2);
        $iHeight = 40;

        $this->_imageCreate($iWidth, $iHeight);

        $nBgColor  = imageColorAllocate($this->_hImg, 255, 255, 255);
        $nTxtColor = imageColorAllocate($this->_hImg, 0, 0, 0);        

        $positionLeft = 20;

        for ($i = 0; $i < $iString; $i++) 
        { 
            imagestring($this->_hImg, 5, $positionLeft, 12,  $sText[$i], $nTxtColor);

            $positionLeft += 15;
        }        
    }

    private function _imageCreate($iWidth, $iHeight)
    {
        $this->_hImg = imageCreate($iWidth, $iHeight);
    }   
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove all the code that use `strtolower()`.

Here the fixed code:

```
<?php
/**
 * [PHPFOX_HEADER]
 */

defined('PHPFOX') or exit('NO DICE!');

/**
 * 
 * 
 * @copyright       [PHPFOX_COPYRIGHT]
 * @author          Raymond Benc
 * @package         Module_Captcha
 * @version         $Id: captcha.class.php 6005 2013-06-06 14:12:12Z Raymond_Benc $
 */
class Captcha_Service_Captcha extends Phpfox_Service 
{
    private $_oSession;

    /**
     * Class constructor
     */ 
    public function __construct()
    {       
        $this->_oSession = Phpfox::getService('log.session');
    }

    public function checkHash($sCode = null)
    {

        if (Phpfox::getParam('captcha.recaptcha'))
        {

            require_once(PHPFOX_DIR_LIB . 'recaptcha' . PHPFOX_DS . 'recaptchalib.php');        
            if (isset($_POST["recaptcha_response_field"])) 
            {           
                $oResp = recaptcha_check_answer(Phpfox::getParam('captcha.recaptcha_private_key'), $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"], $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"], $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

                if ($oResp->is_valid){          
                    return true;
                }else{               
                    return false;
                }           
            }   

            return false;
        }       

        if (Phpfox::getParam('core.store_only_users_in_session'))
        {

            $oSession = Phpfox::getLib('session');

            $sSessionHash = $oSession->get('sessionhash');

            $aRow = $this->database()->select('*')
                ->from(Phpfox::getT('log_session'))
                ->where('session_hash = \'' . $this->database()->escape($sSessionHash) . '\'')
                ->execute('getSlaveRow');

            if (isset($aRow['session_hash']) && $this->_getHash($sCode, $aRow['session_hash']) == $aRow['captcha_hash'])
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        else
        {

            if ($this->_getHash($sCode, $this->_oSession->getSessionId()) == $this->_oSession->get('captcha_hash'))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function setHash($sCode)
    {
        if (Phpfox::getParam('core.store_only_users_in_session'))
        {
            $oRequest = Phpfox_Request::instance();
            $oSession = Phpfox::getLib('session');

            $sSessionHash = $oSession->get('sessionhash');
            $bCreate = true;

            if (!empty($sSessionHash))
            {
                $bCreate = false;
                $aRow = $this->database()->select('*')
                    ->from(Phpfox::getT('log_session'))
                    ->where('session_hash = \'' . $this->database()->escape($sSessionHash) . '\'')
                    ->execute('getSlaveRow');

                if (isset($aRow['session_hash']))
                {
                    $this->database()->update(Phpfox::getT('log_session'), array('captcha_hash' => $this->_getHash($sCode, $sSessionHash)), "session_hash = '" . $sSessionHash . "'");
                }
                else
                {
                    $bCreate = true;
                }
            }

            if ($bCreate)
            {
                $sSessionHash = $oRequest->getSessionHash();
                $this->database()->insert(Phpfox::getT('log_session'), array(
                        'session_hash' => $sSessionHash,
                        'id_hash' => $oRequest->getIdHash(),
                        'captcha_hash' => $this->_getHash($sCode, $sSessionHash),
                        'user_id' => Phpfox::getUserId(),
                        'last_activity' => PHPFOX_TIME,
                        'location' => '',
                        'is_forum' => '0',
                        'forum_id' => 0,
                        'im_hide' => 0,
                        'ip_address' => '',
                        'user_agent' => ''
                    )
                );
                $oSession->set('sessionhash', $sSessionHash);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $iId = $this->_oSession->getSessionId();

            $this->database()->update(Phpfox::getT('log_session'), array('captcha_hash' => $this->_getHash($sCode, $iId)), "session_hash = '" . $iId . "'");
        }
    }

    public function displayCaptcha($sText)
    {
        ((Phpfox::getParam('captcha.captcha_use_font') && function_exists('imagettftext')) ? $this->_writeFromFont($sText) : $this->_writeFromString($sText));

        ob_clean();

        header("X-Content-Encoded-By: phpFox " . PhpFox::getVersion());
        header("Pragma: no-cache");
        header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate'); 
        header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

        imagejpeg($this->_hImg);    
        imagedestroy($this->_hImg);     
    }   

    public function generateCode($sCharacters) 
    {   
        $sPossible = Phpfox::getParam('captcha.captcha_code');
        $sCode = '';
        $i = 0;
        while ($i < $sCharacters) 
        { 
            $sCode .= substr($sPossible, mt_rand(0, strlen($sPossible)-1), 1);
            $i++;
        }      
        return $sCode;
    }       

    /**
     * If a call is made to an unknown method attempt to connect
     * it to a specific plug-in with the same name thus allowing 
     * plug-in developers the ability to extend classes.
     *
     * @param string $sMethod is the name of the method
     * @param array $aArguments is the array of arguments of being passed
     */
    public function __call($sMethod, $aArguments)
    {
        /**
         * Check if such a plug-in exists and if it does call it.
         */
        if ($sPlugin = Phpfox_Plugin::get('captcha.service_captcha__call'))
        {
            return eval($sPlugin);
        }

        /**
         * No method or plug-in found we must throw a error.
         */
        Phpfox_Error::trigger('Call to undefined method ' . __CLASS__ . '::' . $sMethod . '()', E_USER_ERROR);
    }       

    private function _getHash($sCode, $sSalt)
    {
        return md5(md5($sCode) . $sSalt);
    }

    private function _writeFromFont($sText)
    {
        $iString = strlen($sText);
        $iWidth = (($iString + 5) * 10 * 2);
        $iHeight = 45;
        $iTextSize = 20;
        $sFont = Phpfox::getParam('core.dir_static') . 'image/font/' . Phpfox::getParam('captcha.captcha_font');

        if (!file_exists($sFont))
        {
            return $this->_writeFromString($sText);
        }

        $this->_imageCreate($iWidth, $iHeight);

        $nBgColor  = imageColorAllocate($this->_hImg, 255, 255, 255);
        $nTxtColor = imageColorAllocate($this->_hImg, 0, 0, 0);     

        if (!($aBox = @imagettfbbox($iTextSize, 0, $sFont, $sText)))
        {
            return $this->_writeFromString($sText);
        }

        //Find out the width and height of the text box
        $iTextW = $aBox[2] - $aBox[0];
        $iTextH = $aBox[5] - $aBox[3];        

        if (function_exists('imagefilledellipse'))
        {
            $nNoiseColor = imagecolorallocate($this->_hImg, 207, 181, 181);
            for ($i = 0; $i < ($iWidth*$iHeight) / 3; $i++)
            {
                imagefilledellipse($this->_hImg, mt_rand(0, $iWidth), mt_rand(0, $iHeight), 1, 1, $nNoiseColor);
            }
        }

        $iImageLineColor = imagecolorallocate($this->_hImg, 207, 181, 181);
        for ($i = 0; $i < ($iWidth*$iHeight) / 150; $i++)
        {
            imageline($this->_hImg, mt_rand(0, $iWidth), mt_rand(0, $iHeight), mt_rand(0, $iWidth), mt_rand(0, $iHeight), $iImageLineColor);
        }       

        // Calculate the positions
        $positionLeft = (($iWidth - $iTextW) / 2) - (20 + $iString);
        $positionTop = (($iHeight - $iTextH) / 2);

        for ($i = 0; $i < $iString; $i++) 
        { 
            if (!@imagettftext($this->_hImg, $iTextSize, 0, $positionLeft, 30, $nTxtColor, $sFont, $sText[$i]))
            {
                return $this->_writeFromString($sText);
            }

            $positionLeft += 20;
        }
    }

    private function _writeFromString($sText)
    {
        $iString = strlen($sText);
        $iWidth = (($iString + 5) * 6.4 * 2);
        $iHeight = 40;

        $this->_imageCreate($iWidth, $iHeight);

        $nBgColor  = imageColorAllocate($this->_hImg, 255, 255, 255);
        $nTxtColor = imageColorAllocate($this->_hImg, 0, 0, 0);        

        $positionLeft = 20;

        for ($i = 0; $i < $iString; $i++) 
        { 
            imagestring($this->_hImg, 5, $positionLeft, 12,  $sText[$i], $nTxtColor);

            $positionLeft += 15;
        }        
    }

    private function _imageCreate($iWidth, $iHeight)
    {
        $this->_hImg = imageCreate($iWidth, $iHeight);
    }   
}

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You may run into a problem or it could be your solution. Remember, the collation on your database also needs to be taken in consideration. If you are using **utf8_general_ci** then the `ci` means that it is `case insensitive` so no matter what you do on the code side, the database does not care if its upper or lower case. Test that on your search bar, look for some string, lets say a user, ***John Smith***, and then search for the same string as ***john smith***... If the search produces the same result, then your database doesn't care about case sensitive search. I don´t know where your captcha saves its answers, but if it does save them on the database, and its matching your questions in it, then it may not care if it is upper or lower case.

Just a reminder. You need to test that in your own enviroment.